# How could I keep the images of the same size of the slider?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was writing a slider in bootstrap. Below is the comparison of images as seen on a large screen v/s as seen on a mobile-device.

*Laptop screen:*

[image]

*Mobile screen:*

[image]

The result in the mobile screen shows text not on the image and size of the image not fitting the slider. How could I fit the image like it is seen on a laptop screen.

Here is the code for slider :

```
<!-- slider -->
              <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Carousel indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>   
               <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                      <div class="active item">
                          <img src='./images/charity11.jpg' class='img1' />
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3 class='title'>Let Us All Come Together</h3>
                            <em class='subtext'>"..and be a blessing to someone else."</em>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                          <img src='./images/child2.jpg' class='img1' />>
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3 class='title'>Education is the vaccine for violence</h3>
                            <em class='subtext'>"..and love, the poet said, is woman's whole existence."</em>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                          <img src='./images/tree.jpg' class='img1' />
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3 class='title'>Lend a hand to save trees</h3>
                            <em class='subtext'>"..let the green be seen."</em>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                          <img src='./images/dr1.jpg' class='img1' />
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Carousel nav -->
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- slider ends -->
```

Css :

```
.item{
background: #333;    
text-align: center;
height: 420px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the slider scales it's width with the screen, but the height doesn't change because the item class has constant height.

Maybe `@media` queries would do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `height:auto/inherit` so that it would match `carousel-inner` properties. Yo cant define `height: 420px !important;` and expect the same kind of behavior in other dimension screen, You should be using `Media Queries` more info is [here](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)